# I cannot create object that contains arrays of property inside object

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-mvc-3

I am a new developer to c# MVC3.
I have a problem that I cannot create object that contains arrays of property inside object.

For example, I want to create instance ABC.Property[] for 10 arrays.

ABC.Property[0]

ABC.Property[1]

ABC.Property[2]
.....
....
ABC.Property[10]

I used debug mode to check and found out that ABC.Property[] is null. So i cannot add the value back to that object's array.

How to crate object with propeties's array?

thank you.

```
namespace finance3.Models
{
public class Expected_and_Risk
{


    public decimal[] Prop { get; set; }
    public decimal[] Forecast { get; set; }
    public string[] Name { get; set; }
    public decimal[] AxB { get; set; }
    public decimal[] PowAxB { get; set; }


    public decimal  ExpectValue(Expected_and_Risk abc)
    {

        decimal count = abc.Forecast.Count();

        Expected_and_Risk Result = new Expected_and_Risk();

        for (int i = 0 ; i < count ; i++)
        {
            // here is the problem
            // i cannot add new data to array because it has no dimemsion and i tried this
            //
            // Expected_and_Risk[] Result = new Expected_and_Risk[10];
            //
            // but it didn't work

            Result.Name[i] = abc.Name[i];
            Result.Prop[i] = abc.Prop[i];
            Result.Forecast[i] = abc.Forecast[i];
            Result.AxB[i] = abc.Prop[i] * abc.Forecast[i];


            decimal a = Result.AxB[i];
            decimal sumAxB =+ a;

            double temp = (double)(a * a) ;
            Result.PowAxB[i] = (decimal)(temp);

        }

        return Convert.ToDecimal(Result); 
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better way could be to add following method into Expected_and_Risk class  **and call it from within constructor.**

**EDIT**  - edit is done to make Initialize private, and call it within constructor.

```
void Initialize(int size)
{
    Prop = new decimal[size];
    AxB = new decimal[size];
    Forecast = new decimal[size];
    PowAxB = new decimal[size];
    Name = new string[size];
}

    public Expected_and_Risk(int size)
    {
      ....
      Initialize(size);
    }
```

After that use it in ExpectValue like

```
Expected_and_Risk Result = new Expected_and_Risk(size)// size is 10 in example;
```

Comment: Why would you want to use a separate `Initialize` method instead of doing it in the constructor as normal?

Comment: In general if ctor goes beyond 8-10 lines, i prefer different method and call it in ctor. Here it is not required/recommended to have Initialize method as public.  I create public Initialize, Clear methods, when data requires to be reset.

Comment: But having a separate public Initialize method is precisely what your answer recommends. After calling the constructor the object isn't fully initialized, which is never a nice situation and is entirely unwarranted here.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a [Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ace5hbzh.aspx) in your class and in that constructor you can define the size for your property

```
public class Expected_and_Risk
{
//......//your code here
    public Expected_and_Risk()
      {
      this.Prop  = new decimal[10]; // this will define an array of 10 decimal elements for Prop
      }
}
```

Also read about object oriented programming, Also check out this article [An Intro to Constructors in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7011/An-Intro-to-Constructors-in-C)

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, you've got arrays *within* `Expected_and_Risk`, but you're never initializing the variables. You *could* do so within a constructor:

```
public Expected_and_Risk(int count)
{
    Name = new string[count];
    ...
}
```

... but I'd suggest that's actually a nasty design. Any time you have lots of collections, all with the same count, where `x[0]` corresponds to `y[0]` and `z[0]` etc, you should consider having *one* collection of a custom type representing the encapsulation of those properties. For example:

```
// Must be an int, not a decimal - you can't create an array with a decimal count
int count = abc.Forecast.Count();

// Note: rename type to follow .NET naming conventions
Expected_and_Risk[] results = new Expected_and_Risk[count];
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    results[i].Name = abc[i].Name;
    ...
}
```

... except that of course now `abc` would be an array too. (It's not clear whether you're really just trying to copy all the values here, or whether you've got some business logic involved. There are better ways of copying values.)

Alternatively, if you really *do* want collections within `Expected_and_Risk`, you might want to consider using `List<T>` instead of arrays. That way you don't need to specify the count up-front.

Comment: ...and if Expected_and_Risk will be real public class in production code, there must be Collection<T> instead of List<T>.

Comment: @Dennis: Um, no... there's nothing wrong with `List<T>`. You *could* choose to declare the variables to be of type `IList<T>` while using `List<T>` as the concrete class, but I see no reason to use `Collection<T>` here. `Collection<T>` is designed to be a *base* class, and there's no indication that any extra behaviour is required of the collection here.

Comment: List<T> doesn't allow to change behavior when making modifications to collection (add/remove). For example, if developer of Expected_and_Risk will be asked to add an event, when member of collection is inserted, he would force to break public contract. In the case of Collection<T>, he will change only implementation details.

Comment: @Dennis: Where's the evidence that that's a requirement? Or that the `Collection<T>` would actually be exposed? I was suggesting not putting a collection inside `Expected_and_Risk` at all - but if I did, I probably wouldn't expose it directly anyway... I'd expose methods which worked *on* the collection, while keeping it private. Your first blanket comment gives the impression that `List<T>` should never be used in production code, which is entirely inaccurate IMO.

Comment: Agree with private collection. About List<T>: more exactly, List<T> should **never** be used in **public** contracts. Of course, for use in code internals it's ok.

Comment: I think it's fine to be in *some* public APIs, but usually when making a copy. I wouldn't expose a `Collection<T>` directly either. I'd usually only want to expose a read-only wrapper anyway, but if I really wanted to expose a mutable collection, I'd expose it as `IList<T>` at which point the implementation could be just a list until more was required.