# After calculation of arrays, it shows that cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal' , even though I used decimal data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, object, return

[I cannot create object that contains arrays of property inside object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10612677/i-cannot-create-object-that-contains-arrays-of-property-inside-object)

After I fixed the last problem from the link above, I am faced with a new one, and I tried search one posted but I still struck with it.

In the last line I want to use `Result(object)` to view and I don't know how to pass it.

The problem is in the last line (return), it said

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal'

thank you all :)

```
namespace finance3.Models
{
public class Expected_and_Risk
{

    public void Initialize(int size)
    {
        Prop = new decimal[size];
        AxB = new decimal[size];
        Forecast = new decimal[size];
        PowAxB = new decimal[size];
        Name = new string[size];
    }

    public decimal[] Prop { get; set; }
    public decimal[] Forecast { get; set; }
    public string[] Name { get; set; }
    public decimal[] AxB { get; set; }
    public decimal[] PowAxB { get; set; }


    public decimal  ExpectValue(Expected_and_Risk abc)
    {

        int count = abc.Forecast.Count();

        Expected_and_Risk Result = new Expected_and_Risk();
        Result.Initialize(count); 

        for (int i = 0 ; i < count ; i++)
        {


            Result.Name[i] = abc.Name[i];
            Result.Prop[i] = abc.Prop[i];
            Result.Forecast[i] = abc.Forecast[i];
            Result.AxB[i] = abc.Prop[i] * abc.Forecast[i];


            decimal a = Result.AxB[i];
            decimal sumAxB =+ a;

            double temp = (double)(a * a) ;
            Result.PowAxB[i] = (decimal)(temp);

        }
        // here is the problem
        return (Result); 
    }
}

}
```

Comment: What's `Result` ? can't see it's declaration, and obviously, `Result` is not of type `decimal`, so how do you expect the function to return an object that is not the latter?

Comment: **ExpectValue** is declared as returning a *decimal*, but you're trying to return a type *Expected_and_Risk*.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @Shai it's declared as *Expected_and_Risk Result = new Expected_and_Risk();* near the top of the *ExpectValue* method.

Comment: @Shai
I want to return instance named "Result" that created from class to MVC view.
how to fix it?
I am sorry to explain more clearly because i am new  developer c#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to return your custom object, rather than a decimal.

Change:

```
public decimal  ExpectValue(Expected_and_Risk abc)
```

to this:

```
public Expected_and_Risk ExpectValue(Expected_and_Risk abc)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could fix your compilation error by changing the method's signature:

```
public Expected_and_Risk ExpectValue(Expected_and_Risk abc) { //...
```

I have no idea if that makes any sense for your logic, however.

Alternatively if there's a way to convert an `Expected_and_Risk` object to a single numeric value, you could declare a conversion operator or an instance method to calculate that value, and return it instead:

```
return (decimal)Result;
```

or

```
return Result.DistillToDecimalValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you even read the rest of this answer, consider the following: Its improbable to return a class constructor as a another form without proper conversion. (Such as a ToDecimal() method, that you might want to create), so change:

```
public decimal ExpectValue(Expected_and_Risk abc)
```

to:

```
public Expected_and_Risk ExpectValue(Expected_and_Risk abc)
```

Here is my take on this problem:
when you place statement "return (Result);", i believe there are two possible problems.
1) You should have formatted the return statement like so:

```
return (decimal)Result;
```

2) You should have converted the object to a decimal, while checking that the result is a valid decimal (You must create a conversion method "ToString()"):

```
decimal retVal = 0;
if (!decimal.TryParse(Result.ToString(), out retVal)) throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Result"); //put whatever you want inplace of the argumentexception
return retVal;
```

Although i'm sure the solution at the top will work, if it doesnt just try the other two above.

Answer (score 0):

As dbaseman explained a bit, you are returning a Expected_and_Rick class object, while your method return type is decimal.
And about the loop, you will always return only one Expected_and_Rick object, since you override it in a for loop. I would suggest you to create a List, where T will be Expected_and_Rick class.

```
   public List<Expected_and_Risk> ExpectValue(Expected_and_Risk abc)
   {
        int count = abc.Forecast.Count();

        List<Expected_and_Risk> list = new List<Expected_and_Risk>();
        Result.Initialize(count); 

        for (int i = 0 ; i < count ; i++)
        {
            Expected_and_Risk Result = new Expected_and_Risk();
            Result.Name[i] = abc.Name[i];
            Result.Prop[i] = abc.Prop[i];
            Result.Forecast[i] = abc.Forecast[i];
            Result.AxB[i] = abc.Prop[i] * abc.Forecast[i];

            decimal a = Result.AxB[i];
            decimal sumAxB =+ a;

            double temp = (double)(a * a) ;
            Result.PowAxB[i] = (decimal)(temp);
            list.Add(Result);
    }
    return list; 
}
```

And on the other side you can have like:

```
Expected_and_Risk data = ....
List<Expected_and_Risk> list = ExpectValue(data);
```